# Can't get param from tabs ui

Tags: jsp, liferay

When make click on one tab is not possible that appear this tab because wabValue is always Red, i cant get the value, when make click the value of _redirectorportlet_WAR_redirectorportlet_tabValue change but i can't get it :/. How can i get this value and show the tab that the user clicked?

I have a tab like this:

```
<liferay-ui:tabs names="red,white" param="tabValue" tabsValues="red,white" value="<%=tabValue %>">
<c:if test="<%= tabValue.equals("red") %>">
<%@ include file ="red/view.jsp" %> 
</c:if>

<c:if test="<%= tabValue.equals("white") %>">
<%@ include file ="white/view.jspf" %> 
</c:if>

</liferay-ui:tabs>
```

Up i get the param

```
String tabValue = ParamUtil.getString(request, "_redirectorportlet_WAR_redirectorportlet_tabValue", "Red");
```

Always return Red but up at the url i can see tha put this:

```
http://localhost:8080/group/rercer/administracion?_rercerorportlet_WAR_rercerportlet_tabValue=Red
```

What is happen? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to check tab parameter manually all the time.
Please see below code snippet example. liferay-ui tag  will take care of persisting tab value/display.

`<portlet:renderURL var="portletURL"></portlet:renderURL>

   <liferay-ui:tabs param="currTAB" names="tab1,tab2,tab3" refresh="<%= true %>" url="<%=portletURL.toString() %>">

       <liferay-ui:section>

        <%@ include file="tab1.jsp" %>

       </liferay-ui:section>

       <liferay-ui:section>

        <%@ include file="tab2.jsp" %>

       </liferay-ui:section>

       <liferay-ui:section>

        <%@ include file="tab3.jsp" %>

       </liferay-ui:section>

   </liferay-ui:tabs>`